# Why has Yahoo install itself as my 404 page in Google Chrome and how do I remove it?

Tags: google-chrome

Recently, my default 404 action in Google Chrome is to search Yahoo. Can anyone tell me why and how I can turn it off please?

If searched most forums and all the articles are about Yahoo default search rather than 404 replacement.

Comment: whats your chrome version?

Comment: Does this happen with specific 404 page(s) or all of them? Could be a redirect built into the page or a hijack on your system.

Comment: You can turn it on or off by going to the wrench menu → Options → Under the hood, then check or clear Show suggestions for navigation errors.but the chrome version is for older one

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 I'm running the latest Chrome (33.0.1750.146) so only have settings in the menu. And I've unset "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors"

Comment: @MatthewWilliams This is for all 404s.  Looks like I've been hijacked, but can't find anything installed in Common Files in Control Panel!

Answer (score 2):

Since we can now work from it likely being a hijack. Couple places to start:

- Disable all browser extensions. If this solves it add them back one at a time to find the issue.
- Run an antivirus program of your choice
- Run a spyware cleaner of your choice - I personally use [superantispyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/)
- Try a different browser to see if the problem persists. If it does Chrome is the issue. If not it is a system issue.

Give these a try and come back with a result.

Comment: So it's cross browser in FF and Chrome.  Just running a loooonnng scan of SAS.  Will let you know...

Comment: Cross browser? Check your programs there may be some rogue program (search protect by Conduit is usually a common one) that may be installed. Try resetting your browser. Firefox - Help - Troubleshooting Information - Reset Browser. Chrome - Burger Stack - Setting - Advanced Options - Reset Browser Settings (at the bottom).

Comment: I just found a naughty extension I never installed and removed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that the Chrome extensions to blame were called "Domain Error Assistant" and "eBay Shopping Assistant". These invasive extensions were automatically planted when I installed the uTorrent client.